# unable to trigger flask restless postprocessor

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I'm using `Flask-Restless` 0.17.0 and having trouble getting a [preprocessor or postprocessor function](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors) to fire. For reference, I have an SQLAlchemy model that look like:

```
class Transaction(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode)
    description = Column(Unicode)
```

I'm able to register the API endpoint without any trouble, but I can not get this `hello_world` postprocessor to print "hello world" for the life of me:

```
def hello_world(**kwargs):
    print 'hello world'

manager.create_api(
    fraud.data.Transaction
    methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
    postprocessors={'POST_RESOURCE': [hello_world]},
)
```

Am I missing something? Any pointers, hints, etc would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 0.17.0 doesn't support `POST_RESOURCE`. The supported post-processor types appear to be:

- `'GET_SINGLE'` for requests to get a single instance of the model.
- `'GET_MANY'` for requests to get the entire collection of instances of the * model.
- `'PATCH_SINGLE' or`'PUT_SINGLE'` for requests to patch a single instance of the model.
- `'PATCH_MANY'` or `'PATCH_SINGLE'` for requests to patch the entire collection of instances of the model.
- `'POST'` for requests to post a new instance of the model.
- `'DELETE_SINGLE'`
- `'DELETE_MANY'`

For your usage, try `postprocessors={'POST': [hello_world]}`.

References:

- http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/0.12.0/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors
- https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/blob/0.17.0/flask_restless/views.py

Comment: Thanks for your help @Robᵩ. I was looking at the `latest` documentation (the default from google), which apparently changes the API quite a bit. I tried poking around in the source code but was getting lost in my flask n00bness.

Comment: I posted a github issue on the Flask-Restless page to better capture versioning of the documentation. Thanks again for your help https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/485